# node js http post request save cookie

Tags: node.js, cookies, express

I am calling an http post request(login request from another 3rd party server) from node and want to save the cookie for future http requests.

```
var options = {
    host: 'hostname.com',
    port: '80',
    path: '/login.php',
    method: 'POST'
};

var data = qs.stringify({
    uname: "validUsername",
    password: "validPassword"
});

var req = http.request(options, function(response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode);
    console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(response.headers));

    // console.log('Cookies: ' + response.getHeader("Set-Cookie"));
    response.setEncoding('utf8');

    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
    });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

req.write(data);
req.end();
```

How can i access and save the cookie from the response sent by the requested server?

Comment: I found one issue in my code. If you are sending data with post request then add header like this: 
`headers: {  
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length': data.length
}`

where data is what you are sending in post request

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to get the header with `response.headers['set-cookie'];`.

If you need to actually parse them, you could use a module like [cookie](https://github.com/defunctzombie/node-cookie) (what Express uses) or [cookiejar](https://github.com/bmeck/node-cookiejar).

Comment: Actually i tried, but it is giving an error:  Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'getHeader'

Comment: Huh.. well you can use `response.headers` too. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I tried by creating a post request in same node server where in response header i had set the cookie. It works fine. but when i try with 3rd party server, it is coming as undefined. I have checked in chrome dev. tools (in networks) where cookie is coming in post response. The 3rd party server is in php.